# Ruby rails destroy.js Completing with 500 Internal Server Error and nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have Product and Wishitem models and their relationships as follows

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishitems, dependent: :destroy
end

class Wishitem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :customer
    belongs_to  :product
end
```

trying to create and destroy wishitems from product page both works without `remote:true` .Moreover , create.js work perfectly, but destroy complete with `error 500 and id for nil class`.If I refresh the page manually i can see the changes done by the destory.js

the snippet of error message

```
Rendered wishitems/_add_to_list.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered wishitems/destroy.js.erb (4.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
1: <%= link_to wishitems_path(product_id: @product_info.id), method: :post, 
   remote: true do%>
2:   <i class="fa fa-heart-o wish_empty_heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
3: <%end%>
4: <%=puts "customer signed in but this item is not in wishlist yet "%>
```

Products Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product_info = Product.friendly.find(params[:slug])
    @customer = current_customer
    if @customer
      #@wishitem = Wishitem.find_by(params[:product_id])
      @wishitem = @customer.wishitems.find_by(params[:id])
    end   
  end
end
```

Wishitems Controller

```
def create
     current_wish = Product.find(params[:product_id])
     @customer_wishitems = current_customer.wishitems
     @wishitem =  current_customer.wishitems.build
     @wishitem.product = current_wish
     @wishitem.save

     #puts "This #{@wishitem.product_id.name} not exisit in Wishlist, record 
     will be created!"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to wishitems_path}
        format.js 
      end

 end  



def destroy
    # @wishitem = Wishitem.find(params[:id])
    @customer = current_customer
    @wishitem = @customer.wishitems.find_by(params[:product_id])
    @wishitem.destroy
    respond_to do |format|

        format.html {redirect_to wishitems_path}
        format.js 
    end

end
```

product show page

```
<div class="wish_from_remote">
 <!-- if customer signed_in ? -->
     <%if customer_signed_in? %>
 <!-- this product in customer's wish list? -->
        <%if current_customer.wishitems.exists?(product_id: @product_info.id) %>
            <%=render "wishitems/remove_from_list"%>
        <%else %>
 <!-- this product not in customer's wish list? -->
        <%=render "wishitems/add_to_list"%>
        <%end%>  
      <%else%>  
  <!--else customer not signed_in ? => default form-->
       <%=render "wishitems/default_wishlist"%>
      <%end%>
  <!--end-->
</div>
```

relevant partials

_remove_from_list

```
<%=puts "customer signed in and this item in wihslist "%>
  <%= link_to @wishitem, method: :delete, remote: :true do%>
  <i class="fa fa-heart wish_filled_heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<%end%>
```

_add_to_list

```
<%= link_to wishitems_path(product_id: @product_info.id), method: :post, remote: true do%>
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o wish_empty_heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<%end%>
<%=puts "customer signed in but this item is not in wishlist yet "%>
```

_default_wishlist

```
<%=puts "customer_not signed in yet _showing default add to list form"%>
  <%= link_to wishitems_path(product_id: @product_info.id), method: :post do%>
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o wish_empty_heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<%end%>
```

create.js.erb

```
$(".wish_from_remote").html("<%=escape_javascript(render "wishitems/remove_from_list")%>")
$(".wish_container").html("<%=escape_javascript(render "index")%>")

$("#snackbar").text("Item Added to the Wishlist")
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$(".wish_from_remote").html("<%=escape_javascript(render "wishitems/add_to_list")%>")
$(".wish_container").html("<%=escape_javascript(render "index")%>")
$("#snackbar").text("Item Removed from Wishlist")
```

Again, render methods works fine but destroy.js completing with `Completed 500 Internal Server Error`

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to render the partial from `destroy.js.erb`, the partial file actually expects `@product_info` to be defined in the respective controller action. So in your `destroy` action add

```
@product_info = Product.find(params[:id]) // set your params accordingly
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you but still same

Comment: `Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/wishitems_controller.rb:63:in `destroy'`

Comment: can you share the line which is causing the issue ? `app/controllers/wishitems_controller.rb:63`

Comment: `def destroy
        # @wishitem = Wishitem.find(params[:id])
        current_wish = Product.find(params[:product_id]) 
         # @customer_wishitems = current_customer.wishitems
        @wishitem = current_customer.wishitems.find_by(:product_id => current_wish)
        @wishitem.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
         
            format.html {redirect_to wishitems_path}
            format.js 
        end
         
    end`
Line 63 is  `current_wish = Product.find(params[:product_id]) ` do you think i have to set  `if @wishitem.nil?` in wishitems/remove_from_list ?

Comment: which means your `:product_id` is not passed in params. Send the the product_id also in params with something like  `<%= link_to wishitem_path(id: @wishitem.id, product_id: @ product_info.id), method: :delete, remote: :true do%>`.

Comment: Thank you but, if i passed the value it will switchback to 500 state